# Reactjs (Functional Component) Conditional Rendering with OR statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
const App = () =>{
    const condition1 = true
    const condition2 = false
    return (
        <div>
            {condition1 || condition2 && <h1>condition met</h1>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The code above only cares about condition2, condition1 is ignored.
is there a way I can use the OR operator in my jsx?
Also I've tried looking through this https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html and I can't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you want to group the OR?: `(condition1 || condition2) && <h1>...</h1>`

Comment: @NickParsons That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to put parentheses?

```
const App = () =>{
    const condition1 = true
    const condition2 = false
    return (
        <div>
            {(condition1 || condition2) && <h1>condition met</h1>}
        </div>
    )
}
```